# Close modal with second button in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I open a modal with the normal Boostrap 4 method.
It works and I can open and close the modal.

But in my case I need a second button the close the modal. A simple copy of the first button wouldn't work.

I tried the following code:

```
$('#sitenav_close').trigger('click.dismiss.bs.modal')
```

It doesn't work either.
Is there any other method to close a modal with a second button?

Comment: If you could add the broken code, it would be much easier for people to able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4.x, you can manually close a modal with the [.modal('hide')](http://const%20myModal%20=%20new%20bootstrap.Modal(...);) method.

```html
<!-- my modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  ...
  <!-- my alternate close button -->
  <button id="altCloseButton">Alternate close</button>
  ...
</div>

<script>
  // close myModal when my alternate close button is clicked
  const altBtn = document.getElementById("altCloseButton");
  altBtn.onclick = () => $('#myModal').modal('hide');
</script>
```

However, if all you need is a duplicate close button, this is unnecessary, as shown below:

```html
<!-- required Bootstrap resources -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Open demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"><small>.modal-title</small></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        .modal-body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <!-- three identical close buttons -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close 3</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```